# KDE: can't pin a program with "show a launcher when not running" option

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

When I launch a program and then right-click its taskbar button and select "show a launcher when not running", I get a standard plasma shell popup saying that no application is associated with this task.

This is a very fresh Kubuntu that hasn't been messed with. Any ideas on how to solve it are appreciated.

Comment: I have a qite similar problem here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/367118/how-do-i-add-a-starter-for-smartgithg-a-in-kde Different is only that it says "file://java doesen't exist"

Answer (score 3):

I discovered a workaround (not a fix!) with some Trial & Error.

1) Open up ~/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc in a text editor

2) Search for Items= (for me there was only one entry with this prefix)

2a) If you have a APPNAME= line underitems for the affected application, delete it. For me I had a 8k line of base64 encoded text starting chrome=

3) The items line is a CSV string. Look for the file:/// reference to the broken launcher. For me it was google chrome and I had a reference to: file:///opt/google/chrome/chrome?wmClass=google-chrome-stable

4) Navigate to /usr/share/applications/ and find the .desktop file for the application you're trying to run. (If it's not there also look in /usr/share/applications/kde4/ )

5) Replace the entry in the Items=line with the path to the .desktop file but leave ?wmClass and everything after it.

So for me:

file:///opt/google/chrome/chrome?wmClass=google-chrome-stable

became

file:///usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop?wmClass=google-chrome-stable

6) Finally, open konsole and restart plasma with the commands:

- kquitapp plasma-desktop
- plasma-desktop

#### edit: I should also say, if there is no .desktop file there, open an existing one in a text editor and use it as a base to create a new one.