# How do I add a starter for smartgitHG a in kde?

Tags: kubuntu, 13.10, kde4, plasma

I would like to add a starter for

```
~/smartgit/bin/smartgithg.sh
```

In the Taskbar (or how is it called?)

usually If I have started a program, I can right-click on it and say „Einen Starter für dieses Programm anzeigen, wenn es nicht läuft“ (in english I would say "show a launcher when not running")

But for smartgit, If I do that and later want to use it, I just get

> file://java doesen't exist

Or how can I change the launcher?

In `~/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc` I have an entry:

```
file:java?wmClass=SmartGit%2FHg
java=file:java,,java,,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
```

this seems broken somehow.

Is it connected to the fact, that I have installed smartgit in my homedirectory under `~/smartgit/bin/smartgit.sh` ?

Comment: See my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/340040/kde-cant-pin-a-program-with-show-a-launcher-when-not-running-option/385571#385571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you create a symlink in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s ~/smartgit/bin/smartgithg.sh .
```

Then you create a new miniprogramm "Schnellstarter" on your desktop, there you could add a new programm where you can select smartigitHg. You can move that miniprogramm starter to the taskbar.

It creates this starter in `~/.local/share/applications/smartgithg.sh.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment[de]=
Comment=
Exec=smartgithg.sh
GenericName[de]=
GenericName=
Icon=system-run
MimeType=
Name[de]=smartgithg.sh
Name=smartgithg.sh
NoDisplay=true
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```